# Error and no error with the same code: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, indexeddb, dexie

I have problem with my code, it throws an error: `Unhandled Rejection (DataError): Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value.`

While my mate has no such problems with the same code, same git url, clean install of it code gives me error and him good working behaviour of the code.

error throws on db.fieldsets.put()
probably problem is in index or primary key, but the code works on other device, so my guess problem not in the code

dexie_db.js:

```
import Dexie from 'dexie';
const db = new Dexie('fieldsets');
db.version(1).stores({
         fieldsets:'++id, user',

});
```

export default db;

```
import * as global from '../../global';
import getFields from './field-defs';
import db from '../../dexie_DB'

let g_fieldsets = [];

async function readFieldsets(fsetKey){
fsetKey = fsetKey+'_offers'
let res;
const userSets = await db.fieldsets.get(fsetKey);
if(!userSets || userSets.v !== 
process.env.REACT_APP_OFFERS_FIELDSET_VERSION){
    const defaultSets = [{
        name: 'Все поля',
        favourite: true,
        data:getFields().map((it,i)=>({
                name:it.name,
                hidden: false,}))
    },];
    res = defaultSets
    console.log(fsetKey,defaultSets)
    console.log('1')
    console.log(db)
    db.fieldsets.put({
        user: fsetKey,
        v:process.env.REACT_APP_OFFERS_FIELDSET_VERSION,
        data: defaultSets
    })
}else{
    res = userSets.data
}
g_fieldsets = res.map(it=>({
    ...it,
    data:it.data.map(item=>({
        ...item,
        def: getFields().find(def=> item.name===def.name)
    }))
}))
global.events.fieldsetsUpdated.next(null)
}

global.currentUser.subscribe(u=>{
if(u){
    readFieldsets(u.login)
}else{
    g_fieldsets = []
}
})

export function getFieldsets(force){
if(force || !g_fieldsets.length){
    if(!global.currentUser.getValue()){
        return [];
    }
    let _ = (readFieldsets(global.currentUser.getValue().login))
}
return g_fieldsets;
}

export function validate(name, it){
return {
    valid: null,
    msg: null
};
}

export function isEntityValid(it){
if(!it){
    return false
}if(!it.supplierId || !it.supplierId.length){
    return false
}if(!it.amount || it.amount<0){
    return false
}if(!it.offeredPrice || it.offeredPrice<0){
    return false
}
return true;
}
```

maybe there are some drivers, some programs, some stuff that can ruin good workflow

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have already a database installed with the same name and tables but no auto-incremented primary key.

For example, you first executed a code like this:

```js
import Dexie from 'dexie';
const db = new Dexie('fieldsets');
db.version(1).stores({
         fieldsets:'id, user',
});
```

Then, you changed the id to ++id.

Try delete the database in your browser and reopen it. Can be done in devtools, or via Dexie.delete('fieldsets').then(...).